# Data captured when an error code is generated

Tags: obd-ii, ram, mileage

I have a 2015 Ram 1500 that has just over 60,000 miles (107000 km).  They did a diagnostics and there are several transmission error codes.  Is the mileage tracked when the error code is captured.  Trying to see if there is a way to show the failure happened prior to 60,000 miles.

Comment: There is also a problematical code which can cause the transmission to go into a remission state and throw out error code because the computer sensor is full of codes that they send out problematical errors to different parts of your engine that's why you will keep seeing WORNING RED FIX ENGINE LIGHT AND FLASHING CODE NUMBERS .
All you have to do is change your EGR valve and clear the code senders because 60,000 miles is half way broke in you have slot more miles from the MoPar As long as you keep good maintaining when your supposed to that truck will last along long time! Use a computer diagn

Answer (score 1):

For some of the error codes, OEM provides Freeze Frame data. Freeze frame data may have some information regarding the vehicle condition at the time error was recorded. the parameters that are recorded for each error code may change based on manufacturer discretion. so you can see if there is freeze frame data available for your transmission error codes.

Answer (score 0):

No, error codes are stored until cleared.

So that means they can sit in the error code list for days, weeks or months.